# JsonConvert.SerializeObject reads the structure, but not the values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I tried this piece of source code (based on NewtonSoft's JSON NuGet library), for reading a JSON file into a JSON object:

```
string str_File_Content = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
Rootobject existing_root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str_File_Content);
```

... and it almost worked: all JSON objects are loaded into the `existing_root` and in case of arrays, the number of objects seems to be correct.

But: the values of the attributes seem not to be filled in, as you can see here:

JSON file excerpt:

```
{
    "project": {
        "common.DESCRIPTION": "Some information",
```

`existing_root` excerpt in Watch window:

```
Expected    :existing_root.project.commonDESCRIPTION : Some information
Real result :existing_root.project.commonDESCRIPTION : null
```

What can I do in order to make `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` not only handle the structure, but also the values?

Comment: It is likely that there is a type mismatch issue where the json data can't be converted to the type in you object in which case it will leave it as null. I would need to look at the json 
 and the definition of your `Rootobject` to know for sure.

Comment: @YosefBernal: there is no type mismatch, Guru Stron has given the correct answer already but I'm still facing an extra problem, as described in a comment on his answer. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json property name contains "." symbol, which is invalid for C# property name, so you can specify correct name to use during (de)serialization with [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm):

```cs
public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("common.DESCRIPTION")]
    public string commonDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works indeed, but apparently my colleagues have added a dot in every attribute in the JSON file. Do you know a way for Web Essentials (I used their "Paste special, paste JSON as classes" feature) to add this `[JsonProperty("...")` line automatically?

Comment: @Dominique Personally I would look into Json.NET internals to do it automatically during deserialization. One way would be to implement custom [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) or maybe even better - custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)